# Test API toMatchObject() jest expect function

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to check if a response from the body matches partially an object of data "partialLaunchData" . I'm surprised to get this error:
● Test POST   /launches  › It should respond with 201 success created

```
    expect(received).toMatchObject(expected)                                                                     
                                                                                                                 
    - Expected  -  3                                                                                             
    + Received  + 13                                                                                             

      Object {
    -   "mission": "Kepler_155",
    -   "rocket": "Explorer IS1",
    -   "target": "Kepler-186 f",
    +   "launch": Object {
    +     "customer": Array [
    +       "SAFTA",
    +       "NASA",
    +     ],
    +     "flightNumber": 101,
    +     "launchDate": "2022-10-13T21:24:59.189Z",
    +     "mission": "Kepler Exploration x",
    +     "rocket": " Explorer IS1",
    +     "success": true,
    +     "target": "Kepler-442",
    +     "upcoming": true,
    +   },
      }

      42 |         const responseDate= Date(response.body.launchDate).valueOf();
      43 |         expect(responseDate).toBe(requestDate);
    > 44 |         expect(response.body).toMatchObject(partialLaunchData);
         |                               ^
      45 |     })
      46 |     //tests on the propreties sent
      47 |     test('It should catch missing required propreties', ()=>{});

      at Object.toMatchObject (src/routes/launches/launches.test.js:44:31)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 3 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.452 s
Ran all test suites.
```

This is my Code in the launches.test.js file describing a post Test on launches path "/launches" .

```
  describe(   'Test POST   /launches ', ()=> {
        // test the response 
        const completeLaunchData={
            // flightNumber: 100,
            mission: 'Kepler Exploration x',
            rocket: ' Explorer IS1',
            launchDate: new Date(),
            target: 'Kepler-442',
            // customer: ['SpaceX, NASA'],
            // upcoming: true,
        }
        const partialLaunchData={
            // flightNumber: 100,
            mission: 'Kepler_155',
            rocket: 'Explorer IS1',
           target: 'Kepler-186 f', 
           
            // upcoming: true,
        }
     
        test('It should respond with 201 success created', async()=>{
            const response = await request(app).post('/launches')
               // comparing two dates and joining them in one format  : we will compare the value of the two dates
            .send( 
              completeLaunchData
            )
            .expect('Content-Type',/json/)
            .expect(201); 
        
            const requestDate = Date(completeLaunchData.launchDate).valueOf(); 
            const responseDate= Date(response.body.launchDate).valueOf(); 
            expect(responseDate).toBe(requestDate);
            expect(response.body).toMatchObject(partialLaunchData);
        })
```

Who has an idea about the issue ? I need help please.